# Can not find part of the path when using the copy command

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm developing a project in WPF and I want to make a photo gallery, I'm trying to copy the photos from my computer to a folder inside my project.

when I run the following command `File.Copy (PathImage, PathPaste);`

Error Message: Could Not Find Part of Path

My variable `pathImage` has the value `C:\\Users\\bruhh\\Desktop\\img.png`
and a variable PathPaste has the value `"C:\\Users\\bruhh\\Desktop\\Photos\\Photos\\Imgs\\1\\"`

I retrieve the path of my project using the command

```
CaminhoProjeto = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName + @"\"+Imgs+@"\" ;
```

Why does this error happen? How do I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure the `Imgs/1` folder exists?

Comment: yes, I have the Imgs folder and inside it a folder with the name 1 and I want to save the images inside it

Comment: You should include the name of the image also in the desination path. Now you only have an folder name.

Answer (score 4):

Second parameter should be file name not directory as in document

```
The name of the destination file. This cannot be a directory or an existing file.

File.Copy(@"C:\Source.txt", "D:\Destination.txt");
```

if you want them to have the same name use

```
var sourceFileInfo = new FileInfo(sourceFile);
File.Copy(sourceFile, $"{destinationDirectory}{sourceFileInfo.Name}");
```

Comment: But how can I copy an image from my computer to a folder in my project

Comment: Give destination file a name as in answer

Comment: Okay, I'll try to do that.